# What are the uses for If-None-Match with multiple entities?

Tags: http, caching, browser-cache, rfc2616

I'm using the `ETag` header for caching and the browser sends a corresponding `If-None-Match` header. Initially, I simply compared these headers and it worked.

Later it occurred to me that [rfc2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) allows a list of entities, so I fixed it. The question is, if the fix gets ever used...

- Does the browser ever issue a request with an `If-None-Match` header containing more than one entity?
- Are there any other real world uses?

Comment: You may want to refer to [RFC 7230](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230)ff. 2616 is obsolete for quite some time now. The problem still exists, though. I'll look into it later, sounds interesting :)

Comment: Right of the bat: Could be versioning schemes such as those used by WebDAV have need for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two use cases that I can think of: union of browser and caching proxy entity-tags and custom client-side cache implemenation.

Although, I never seen browser serves request with multiple entity-tags in `If-None-Match`, there are caching proxies that may have it's own version of a requested resource. They may replace value of `If-None-Match` sent by browser with union of browser's resource version entity-tag and proxy resource version(s) entity-tag before sending request further to server. This way if proxy has fresh version of a requested resource you can reduce server load by serving full response (with body payload) from proxy instead of a server. This case is described by [RFC 7234 Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1): Caching](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.3.2):

> When a cache decides to revalidate its own stored responses for a
> request that contains an If-None-Match list of entity-tags, the cache
> MAY combine the received list with a list of entity-tags from its own
> stored set of responses (fresh or stale) and send the union of the
> two lists as a replacement If-None-Match header field value in the
> forwarded request.

I can't say whether support of that part of RFC 7234 is wide, but certainly there are proxies that support it. Check [Node.js Caching Reverse HTTP Proxy](https://github.com/colinmollenhour/node-caching-proxy) project by Colin Mollenhour.

On the other hand you may not want to rely on browser to perform conditional request. You can set `If-None-Match` HTTP header value by yourself using `XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader()`. This can be useful if you store multiple versions of a resource using [Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API), [Cache API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache) or other mechanism. Server response must contain `ETag` HTTP header with entity-tag. This entity-tag indicates which version of a resource is considered fresh.

Answer (score 2):

I've been reading a lot about caching mechanisms recently and found myself asking this very same question. I can think of only use case (in addition to the ones Leonid mentioned) where it would make sense to store and send multiple `ETags` : when a ressource **rollbacks**.

It could be **accidental**, such as an api that serves json, and the underlying data gets updated often, in ways that it gets restored to a previous version.

But it could also be **by design**, where a big configuration object would have only a few different versions possible, that would get switched a lot. (the frequency at which it would be changed is important, otherwise caching wouldn't bring a lot value). In this case, caches would be happy to have all available versions always ready to be served.

I know that's a long shot, and I can't think of any real situation that would fit one of these. Besides, revalidation suck anyway, cache hits are the way to go =)

Also, you might wanna read [this](https://www.mnot.net/blog/2017/03/16/browser-caching). It appears all caches store only the last sent `ETag` (which is comprehensible for obvious memory reasons).

Hope this helps